# Kryo serialization/deserialization

Tags: java, kryo

I'm trying to use kryo to serialize and deserialize to binary. I think I have the serialization working but I cannot seem to deserialize. Below is the code I'm messing around with but eventually I want to store a byte[] and later read it again. The documentation only shows how to do it with files.

```
        Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
        kryo.register(ArrayList.class);
        kryo.register(Modifier.class);

        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Modifier modifier = new Modifier();
        modifier.type = "Yo swa!";
        modifier.amount = 10;

        Output output = new Output(b);
        kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, modifier);

        System.out.println("Kryo size: " + output.toBytes().length);

        Input input = new Input(output.getBuffer());

        //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 11, Size: 0
        Modifier r = kryo.readObject(input, Modifier.class);
        //Same error:
        Modifier r = kryo.readObject(new Input(new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toBytes())), Modifier.class);

        System.out.println(r.type);
```

Comment: I think you need to specify a size in byte somewhere, just like you would for allocating an array. What is `b`?

Comment: @Dici The ByteArrayOutputStream. If I set an input stream of say byte[100] I get a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2` on the same line.

Comment: You should use `toBytes` instead of `getBuffer` (see the doc http://javadox.com/com.esotericsoftware.kryo/kryo/2.23.0/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/io/Output.html#getBuffer%28%29), but that I don't think it is not what is causing your problem. Whhat is displayed by your first `println` ?

Comment: @dici the size of the array (13). Could that be right? The class I'm serializing holds another int.

Comment: @dici I changed the line of the error to this: `Modifier r = kryo.readObject(new Input(new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toBytes())), Modifier.class);` still the same error though..

Comment: You are using `writeClassAndObject` but reading with `readObject`. You should whether write with `writeObject` or read with `readClassAndObject`

Comment: @Dici Yeah that is it. I kept thinking I was doing something wrong before that line. Pretty nice, I tried serializing with java and ended up with 280 bytes. Kryo cuts it down for me to 23 bytes I guess that is ok to store in my DB. Thanks!

Comment: I did not know Kryo compressed that much. I know it's faster, and more flexible (don't need to tag all the classes as `Serializable`, possesses default serializers for trivial data objects etc)

Comment: @Dici I guess it's because it does not serialize the class, or rather keeps that information somewhere else since `.register`. So it only needs whats in it. And a `null` `Integer` is just 1 byte, who would have thought that? :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You serialize by `writeClassAndObject` method and deserialize by `readObject` which are not compatible.

You should use either `writeClassAndObject` => `readClassAndObject` or `writeObject` => `readObject`.

The following works to me (kryo version 2.21).

**`writeObject` =>`readObject`**

```
package test;

import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
        kryo.register(ArrayList.class);
        kryo.register(Modifier.class);

        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Modifier modifier = new Modifier();
        modifier.type = "Yo swa!";
        modifier.amount = 10;

        Output output = new Output(b);
        kryo.writeObject(output, modifier);
        output.flush();
        output.close();

        System.out.println("Kryo size: " + output.toBytes().length);

        Input input = new Input(output.getBuffer());

        Modifier r = kryo.readObject(input, Modifier.class);

        System.out.println(r.type);
    }

    static class Modifier {
        String type;
        int amount;
    }
}
```

**`writeClassAndObject` => `readClassAndObject`**

```
package test;

import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
        kryo.register(ArrayList.class);
        kryo.register(Modifier.class);

        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Modifier modifier = new Modifier();
        modifier.type = "Yo swa!";
        modifier.amount = 10;

        Output output = new Output(b);
        kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, modifier);
        output.flush();
        output.close();

        System.out.println("Kryo size: " + output.toBytes().length);

        Input input = new Input(output.getBuffer());

        Modifier r = (Modifier) kryo.readClassAndObject(input);

        System.out.println(r.type);
    }

    static class Modifier {
        String type;
        int amount;
    }
}
```